# How to increase SharePoint performance?

Tags: sharepoint-server, performance, architecture, topology

Our SharePoint has 2 WFE server and we are facing performance issue.

What are the things that have to be considered to increase performance?

Comment: What specifications does the server have? How is the stress on the DB server?

Comment: Very generic question. You have to specify more information. There could be a lot reasons: 1. Hardware. What are parameters of your servers? Usually the bottle neck is SQL server performance. 2. Infrastructure. What services you are turned on? Is Search running and how it is configured? If there is a lot data, maybe you should run search services on dedicated server. 3. Information architecture. You should pay attention to site collection structure, sizes of content databases. How many items are in your list and is the data correctly organized into folders? Another issue could be a lot of uniq

Answer (score 1):

Their are couple of reasons which cause the performance issue.

1. High CPU utilization on WFE, Memory Usage on WFE
2. High CPU and Memory Usage on the Database Traffic
3. Unuassal Traffic on the sharepoint
4. Structure the Farm/ site collections in a way it exceeds the MSFT recomendations i.e

   - List views threshold violate
   - number of columns
   - number of web applications in Farm
   - number of App Pools on server
   - number of content DB
5. 3rd party tools also cause the performance issue.

You can setup the perf mon counters on the wfe to check the performance etc.

Please have a look on following links.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2014/11/18/how-to-troubleshoot-performance-issues-in-sharepoint-custom-code-on-your-own-part-1-high-memory-usage.aspx

http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-sluggishness-server-side-issues/#.VjJVtrerSCg

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396